# Overlap UX/SO users

Tags: discussion

Is there a possibility to know how many users here on UX.SE are also in the StackOverflow community?

I'm actually seeking for demographic data about UX.SE and wonder whether the [SO demographics](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/survey-results/) would be a good approximation.