# Are most UX.SE users originally StackOverflow users?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, user-accounts, users

I found my way here after using StackOverflow for a couple of years. There is now a wide range of StackExchange sites, from UX to Cooking.

**It seems like** most users around the network has a love for facts, scrutinization, proving skills and sharing knowledge. I would call us nerds. I mean that as a [good thing](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Nerd&defid=326454). Whether you like to nerd it up with UX, cooking, parenting or photography, is revealed in your SE network accounts.

You see where I am going. It hit me that all the users actually could be computer nerds. *It all started with StackOverflow*. I do not know anyone who knows about *any* SE site, that is not a programmer. There are already a bunch of cooking sites around the web. There are other English sites and there are other UX sites. Their users are not like the users of `{Cooking, English, UX}.StackExchange.com`.

**The question:** Is the user base of UX.StackExchange basically programmers who found their way here from StackOverflow, just like me? Is there any SO-UX correlated account or reputation comparison statistics?

---

Related question: [Overlap UX/SO users](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/777/overlap-ux-so-users)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Overflow is how most Stack Exchange users seem to find any of the other sites at this point, so yeah I'd say it's safe to assume a good amount of UX.SE people are from or have used SO/SU/SF.

The thing is Stack Overflow was hugely popular and for the most part all the sites were born of users of SO. Stack Exchange is trying to grow to not just be a network of programmers that have other interests, but building up that sort of general brand is hard.

I wouldn't say we're all *programmers* rather than UX designers though; many designers that work with CSS or HTML end up on Stack Overflow even if they're not programmers by job title.

Actually, I found some extremely strong evidence from our [Area51 commitment phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728?phase=commitment):

> committers active in
>   83.0% Stack Overflow
>   80.4% User Experience

So, out of people who * committed* to the site, slightly more participated in SO than participated here...so that's our base audience. We've grown a LOT since then but a fair number of our active users came form SO.

Comment: On what do you base the assumption that most UX users found it through SO?

Comment: @JOG Most users seem to find the Stack Exchange *network* through SO, which leads to UX. It's intentional that SO users stumble on other sites as well. I don't have numbers though, and I don't believe there's any offical way to actually compare cross-site users directly

Comment: I'm sure the data exists somewhere; specifically, a graph if the linked accounts created would almost certainly show that the majority of users started at a very popular SE site such as SO, and then activated accounts on other more specific sites later. The account information is public and could be mined if proof was required.

Answer (score 4):

I can only speak for myself, but I was **not** a StackOverflow user prior to getting involved on UX.SE (though I was quite familiar with it).  My participation on UX.SE has actually led me to get somewhat involved on SO and other SE sites, actually.

Comment: OH hey, you're from Wolfram Research! Neat stuff

Comment: @BenBrocka Yup... it's a fun place; always new things that we're working on.

Comment: I came in through Judaism.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I think some UX professionals, like me, may have first heard of UX.SE through the [Balsamiq website](http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2012/02/27/uxstackexchange/). If Peldi and co. at Balsamiq recommend **anything** strongly, I pay attention. As usual, they weren't wrong :)

Comment: Great to have you :) The Balsamiq blog post has had a great and lasting effect on our activity levels.

Comment: +1 similar to my way to UX.SE

Answer (score 0):

I followed in through Coding Horror, but never quite kept up with SO enough to get very far over there. I can't even remember what my username over there is.